# Weird characters for export in .csv

Tags: javascript, typescript, csv, export-to-csv

from a text file with accents I want to make it a .csv file that we can download

```
      let data = decodeURI('a;b;é;É');
      this.download(data, 'test.csv', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8');
```

here the code to download:

```
  download(content, fileName, mimeType): boolean {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8';

    a.href = 'data:' + mimeType + ',' + encodeURIComponent(content);
    a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    setTimeout(() => {
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 66);
    return true;
  }
```

I have strange accents in excell :

test.csv

```
a    b    Ã©    Ã‰
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `'\ufeff'` to your data  `let data = '\ufeff'+decodeURI('a;b;é;É');`, take look at **UTF with BOM** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: '\ufeff'   doen't work !

Comment: @nukmaccon did you tried the updated solution?

Comment: '\ufeff'+decodeURI('a;b;é;É');     it work !